# "npx tsc --version" reports different TypeScript version inside virtual machine

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, tsc, npx

I want to be able to run `npx tsc` on my project on both my host + guest operating systems.  But the guest is using a different (older) version of `tsc` - and I'm not sure where it's coming from.

My setup:

- Host OS: Windows 10
- Guest OS: Debian 9
- I'm using VirtualBox, and the guest is mounting the host's files using VirtualBox's "shared folders" feature - so it doesn't have a separate copy of the project files - my project is accessed through shared folders at all times.
- I do NOT have Typescript installed globally (npm -g) on either the host or guest OS (to confirm this, running `npm -g ls typescript` on both host+guest shows "empty", and running "tsc" alone does not work, as expected).

I have a project with TypeScript 3.3.3333 installed into the project with NPM.

**On the Windows host OS, when I `cd` to the project folder and run:**

- `npm ls typescript` I see output: `typescript@3.3.3333` (as expected)
- `npx tsc --version` I see output: `Version 3.3.3333` (as expected)

**Inside the Linux guest OS, when I `cd` to the project folder and run:**

- `npm ls typescript` I see output: `typescript@3.3.3333` (as expected)
- `npx tsc --version` I see output: `message TS6029: Version 1.5.3` (**unexpected!**)

So I'm unable to run `npx tsc` to compile my code inside the guest, as it doesn't support some of my newer tsconfig settings.

Where could this tsc 1.5.3 version be coming from, and how do I get rid of it?

Or is there some alternative NPM command I can run on the host that will install a usable `tsc` into the project that works for both Windows+Linux?

Also, none of the parent folders ***above*** my project's root have a `node_modules` folder (but of course my project's root does have its node_modules sub-folder).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

TypeScript binary is called `tsc` for shortness. When it's not installed globally, `npx` has no way to know that `tsc` refers to `tsc` binary for `typescript` package. `npx tsc` refers to [deprecated `tsc` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc).

A way this can be fixed is to specify package name explicitly:

```
npx -p typescript tsc
```

And the actual problem here is that the project relies on global TypeScript installation. It's common to have `typescript` a project was written with in project dependencies and refer to local installation in package.json NPM scripts:

```
...
"scripts": {
  "build": "tsc"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "typescript": "~3.3.0"
"
...
```

Comment: Thanks, it appears that `npx -p typescript tsc` does what I need, and correctly reports version 3.3.3333.

I'm curious how the old "tsc" package was being run?  Because I don't have it installed in the project or globally, and the string "tsc" doesn't even exist anywhere inside my package.json or package-lock.json files.  No "tsc" folder under node_modules either.   Also `npx tsc --version` was reporting `message TS6029: Version 1.5.3` - which doesn't appear to be a version number for the "tsc" package? (which uses a different format for its version numbers).

Comment: I can't find any "tsc" package anywhere on the host or guest filesystems.  Does npx temporarily download a copy and delete it after running or something like that? (I see a message `npx: installed 1 in 1.998s` when I run it)  Or otherwise where could the "tsc" package files be coming from?

Comment: Yes, that's what npx does. It installs a temporary copy. That tsc has the latest 1.20150623.0 version and not 1.5.3 means that the package uses different version internally to show with `-v` and doesn't get it from package.json.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand why npx don' get new version of TSC?

Comment: @MuradSofiyev It uses globally installed TS in case there's one. Use `npx --ignore-existing -p typescript tsc` if you want it to behave differently.

Comment: Yeah but I don't have any globally installed TS this is mean npx must get download lates version of tsc and execute. Am I wrong? But npx download old version of TypeScript :/

Comment: @MuradSofiyev What version? Did you check that it's not installed? That you have this problem suggests the opposite.