# Why does `npx tsc --init` use an old version (V1.5.3) but newer (V4.1.3) after npm i typescript is installed?

Tags: javascript, npm

When using `npx tsc --init` without typescript installed, NPM seems to go through the motions to download `tsc`, and has some commands, but not all (it doesn't have `--init`), and I realize its because its using a really old version of `tsc`. Thats annoying, it should use the latest one :)

To reproduce this yourself, make sure you don't have typescript installed globally and also are not in a NPM project (with package.json). Then type `npx tsc --version`: you will get

```
npx: installed 1 in 0.868s
message TS6029: Version 1.5.3
```

Obviously the workaround is to install typescript first, but then there is no point of `npx`, is there? Only then do I get the latest version:

```
Version 4.1.3
```

Answer (score 2):

As Estus Flask said in his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55138585/7365866), when you use `tsc` without typescript installed, you are using the deprecated tsc [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc), which I personally wasn't able to find using https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=tsc probably because it has fallen way down in the search ranking.

His answer has more detail and tips to make `npx` still work without installing typescript: `npx -p typescript tsc` (-p means "Package to be installed.")

---

After typing the question, it looks like a similar question has been asked before. But this question has got nothing to do with virtual machines (the original question): ["npx tsc --version" reports different TypeScript version inside virtual machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55138134/npx-tsc-version-reports-different-typescript-version-inside-virtual-machine)